# Publishing on arXiv before submitting to an IEEE journal

Tags: arxiv, ieee

Since the review process for IEEE journals can take upto an year, I want to publish my paper on arXiv to make it available to the research community. I read that in order to have the paper on both arXiv and IEEE, I should submit to arXiv first and then to IEEE. But once the article is submitted to arXiv, it takes time to be announced and publicly available. So, should I submit to IEEE only after the article is announced on arXiv or can I submit to IEEE as soon as I've submitted to arXiv?

Comment: See: https://journals.ieeeauthorcenter.ieee.org/become-an-ieee-journal-author/publishing-ethics/guidelines-and-policies/policy-posting-your-journal-article/

Comment: Thanks! I had read that. My concern was not clarified there.

Comment: "I should submit to arXiv first and then to IEEE" -- is that field specific? Can you provide a source for this?

Comment: If the IEEE page didn't answer your question, what do you need to know in addition?

Comment: @GoodDeeds, I had read this somewhere on the web. I couldn't find it now. It said something along the lines of "Posting on arXiv before submitting to IEEE would give distributing rights to arXiv first and hence IEEE cannot forbid it. If I submit to IEEE first, then I can submit to arXiv only after the paper is accepted/rejected".

Comment: @Buffy, please read my above comment. That information caused me concern. On the IEEE page, there is no description of the chronology I should follow. It says "IEEE allows authors to post on arXiv", but there may be some hidden clause saying "IEEE allows authors to post on arXiv, only if the paper is posted on arXiv first". I don't know if there is such a thing, I'm just worried and want to make sure I don't muck it up!